# Initialize git submodule from local repo, then update from remote

Tags: git, github, deployment

I'm working on a deploy that, at first, clones the previous release and then secondly, updates the release from the remote repo. This gets tricky when there are submodules involved. The main repo is handled like this:

```
git clone /path/to/local/.git /path/to/new/release
git remote set-url origin <my remote repo>
```

That way subsequent calls to git pull will use the remote repo. What I'd like to do is the same thing for the submodules within the repo. In pseudocode:

```
git submodule foreach 'git clone each submodule from local repo'
git submodule foreach 'git pull from remote repo'
```

I've read quite about this and can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is in the clone command:

```
git clone --recursive --config submodule.<name>.url=/path/to/local/repo
```

This will ensure that on the initial clone, we take from the local repo. Then if you have your `.gitmodules` setup properly, subsequent pulls will be from the remote repo.